# HashMap - Fastest access using a key with several fields

Tags: java, hashmap

I have an object that is identified by 3 fields. One them is a String that represents 6 hex bytes, the other two are integers of not more than 1 bytes each. This all summed up is 8 bytes of data, which fits in a 64 bit integer.

I need to map these objects for fast access, and I can think of two approaches:

- Use the 3 fields to generate a 64 bit key used to map the objects. This however would mean parsing the String to Hex for every access (and there will a lot of accesses, which need to be fast).
- Use 3 HashMap levels, each nested inside the next, to represent the 3 identifying fields.

My question is which of these approaches should be the fastest.

Comment: Why don't you simply try both approaches and see for yourself?

Comment: I would create a class for the key fields, store it inside the objects, and also use it a the key for the map

Comment: Your 3 maps would be much more: it is just 3 levels, each level having a multitude of maps...

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion for you. 
Create an object with the 3 attributes that will form the key. Use the object has the key because it will be unique.

```
Map<ObjectKey,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
```

This makes sense for your use case? If you can add a bit more explanation maybe I can go further in suggest you possible solutions.

EDIT: You can override the equals and do something using this kind of logic:

```
@Override   
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (!(obj instanceof Key))
        return false;
      ObjectKey objectKey= (Key) obj;
      return this.key1.equals(objectKey.key1) && this.key2.equals(objectKey.key2) &&
          ...
          this.keyN.equals(objectKey.keyN)
   }
```

Comment: The main thing here is that you _must_ define the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods for `ObjectKey`. So how do you define them? That's a main part of the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a MultiKeyMap?
This might be not related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the following steps:

1. Write it in the most readable way first, and profile it.
2. Refactor it to an implementation you think might be faster, then profile it again.
3. Compare.
4. Repeat.

Your key fits into a 64-bit value. Assuming you will build the HashMap in one go and then read from it multiple times (using it as a lookup table), my hunch is that using a `Long` type as the key of your HashMap will be about as fast as you can get.

You are concerned about having to parse the string as a hex number every time you look up a key in the map. What's the alternative? If you use a key containing the three separate fields, you will still have to parse the string to calculate its hash code (or, rather, the Java API implementation will calculate its hash code by parsing the string contents). The HashMap will not only call `String.hashCode()` but also `String.equals()`, so your string will be iterated *twice*. By contrast, calculating a `Long` and comparing it to the precalculated keys in the HashMap will consist of iterating the string only once.

If you use three levels of `HashMap`, as per your second suggestion, you will still have to calculate the hash code of your string, as well as having to look up the values of all three fields anyway, so the multi-level map doesn't give you any performance advantage.

You should also experiment with the HashMap constructor arguments to get the most efficiency. These will determine how efficiently your data will get spread into separate buckets.